# How do you select a certain number from a phone's address book?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

How do you select a certain number from a phone's address book?

I get a contact from the Address book, but only mobile number is retrieved. What should I do to enable user to select mobile/home/other number?

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)pickContact
{
    // creating the picker
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    // showing the picker
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    // releasing
    [picker release];

}
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    // assigning control back to the main controller
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    Contact *cont=[[Contact alloc] init];

    // setting the first name
    cont.fName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    // setting the last name
    cont.lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);   

    // setting the number
    /*
     this function will set the first number it finds

     if you do not set a number for a contact it will probably
     crash
     */



    //ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    //  cont.number = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(
                                                         person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    CFIndex numPhoneNums = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);
    if(numPhoneNums == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No number available");
        cont.number = @"No number available";
    } else {
        cont.number = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0);
    }
```

...The rest works alright.

Answer (score 2):

To get all type of phone numbers...(person is an instance of ABRecordRef)

```
    NSMutableArray *arPhList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
    {       
        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);   
        NSString *phoneLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j));
        NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;            
        NSDictionary *dicTemp = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:phoneNumber,@"value", phoneLabel,@"label", nil];  
        [arPhList addObject:dicTemp];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
        cont.number = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, **0**);
    }
```

"phones" has all phone numbers (mobile, home, fax, etc)

But you only use index **0**.

You use only first phone number. (It would be not mobile.)

Use for loop (numPhoneNums) to access all numbers.